How to get the referenced value of a formula cell in the correct data type with SlapKit.Excel?
I'm working on a report generator using SlapKit.Excel. Some reports reference other sheets using formulas like =Sheet1!A1. This works fine in the produced Excel file, but when I try to programmatically get the value of the formula cell, I get a System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.. In my case, the data type is DateTime.
I managed to narrow down the problem to:
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.AddWorksheet();
worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = DateTime.Now;
worksheet.Cell(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R1C1";
Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value.GetDateTime());

The code produces an InvalidCastException. I tried to change the number format as well. While this changes the number format of the formula cell in the output file, it doesn't solve the issue:
worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Style.NumberFormat = worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Style.NumberFormat;

If I check the Type property, it says it is of type Number:
Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value.Type);

How can I instruct SlapKit.Excel that this cell is of type DateTime, so I don't run into the exception?

Eventually, I managed to find a reasonable solution:
if (worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value.TryConvert(out DateTime dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}

In my case, as I'm generating the Excel file I know the content of the cell is a DateTime so I did it as a sanity check:
if (!worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value.TryConvert(out DateTime dateTime))
    throw new Exception(); // Sanity check. This should never happen.

Console.WriteLine(dateTime);

